# How to connect Lumen framework with Kafka queue

Tags: php, apache-kafka, lumen

I have a project with Lumen framework. Needs to add queue with Kafka, I found only this package(but for laravel) [laravel-queue-kafka](https://github.com/rapideinternet/laravel-queue-kafka) and tried to install, but I got errors:

```
    Problem 1
    - Installation request for rapide/laravel-queue-kafka ^1.0 -> satisfiable by rapide/laravel-queue-kafka[1.0].
    - Conclusion: remove doctrine/inflector 2.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/inflector 2.0.3
    - rapide/laravel-queue-kafka 1.0 requires illuminate/support 5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.0 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.0.x-dev, 1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.0, v1.0.1, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.13 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.0.x-dev, 1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.0, v1.0.1, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.17 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.0.x-dev, 1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.0, v1.0.1, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.19 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.0.x-dev, 1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.0, v1.0.1, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.27 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.0.x-dev, 1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.0, v1.0.1, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.9 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.0.x-dev, 1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.0, v1.0.1, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support 5.4.x-dev requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support 5.5.x-dev requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support 5.6.x-dev requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support 5.7.17 requires doctrine/inflector ^1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support 5.7.18 requires doctrine/inflector ^1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support 5.7.19 requires doctrine/inflector ^1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support 5.7.x-dev requires doctrine/inflector ^1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support v5.4.36 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.0 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.16 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.17 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.2 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.28 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.33 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.34 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.35 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.36 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support v5.5.37 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 
...................
    - illuminate/support v5.7.8 requires doctrine/inflector ^1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.9 requires doctrine/inflector ^1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.4.0, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.4.1, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.4.2, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.4.3, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.4.x-dev, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.0.x-dev, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.2.x-dev, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.3.1, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.3.x-dev, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[v1.0, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[v1.0.1, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[v1.1.0, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[v1.2.0, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[v1.3.0, 2.0.3].
    - Installation request for doctrine/inflector (locked at 2.0.3) -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[2.0.3].
```

Then I removed doctrine inflector and tried to install once more and got:

```
- Installation request for rapide/laravel-queue-kafka ^1.0 -> satisfiable by rapide/laravel-queue-kafka[1.0].
    - Conclusion: remove illuminate/console v7.28.3
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/console v7.28.3
    - rapide/laravel-queue-kafka 1.0 requires illuminate/queue 5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/queue[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - illuminate/queue 5.4.x-dev requires illuminate/console 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - illuminate/queue v5.4.0 requires illuminate/console 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - illuminate/queue v5.4.13 requires illuminate/console 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - illuminate/queue v5.4.17 requires illuminate/console 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - illuminate/queue v5.4.19 requires illuminate/console 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - illuminate/queue v5.4.27 requires illuminate/console 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - illuminate/queue v5.4.36 requires illuminate/console 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - illuminate/queue v5.4.9 requires illuminate/console 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - illuminate/queue 5.5.x-dev requires illuminate/console 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.5.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
    - illuminate/queue v5.5.0 requires illuminate/console 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.5.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
    - illuminate/queue v5.5.16 requires illuminate/console 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.5.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
    - illuminate/queue v5.5.17 requires illuminate/console 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.5.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
    - illuminate/queue v5.5.2 requires illuminate/console 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.5.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
    - illuminate/queue v5.5.28 requires illuminate/console 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.5.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
    - illuminate/queue v5.5.33 requires illuminate/console 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.5.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/console[v5.7.9, v7.28.3].
    - Installation request for illuminate/console (locked at v7.28.3) -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[v7.28.3].
```

Maybe anyone have an experience with Lumen and Kafka, or have link for good documentation about this?

Answer (score 0):

You have laravel 7.28, and rapide/laravel-queue-kafka is compatible with laravel <= 5.6 currently. You have to pick other library.